# How to retrieve two istream values from a function

Tags: c++, cin

I have a function that prompts for two string values in one function and then returns those two strings. I need to use those two separately in a different function. How can I access both?

Here is the prompt function:

```
string othello::get_user_move( ) const
{
    string column; 
    string row;

    display_message("Enter Column: ");
    getline(cin, column); // Take value one.
    display_message("Enter Row: ");
    getline(cin, row);  //Take value two.
    return column, row; //return both values.
}
```

Here is the code that is trying to use it (it's derived from another game that was given to us to modify and the original here only grabs one value):

```
void othello::make_human_move( )
{
    string move;

    move = get_user_move( ); // Only takes the second value inputted.
    while (!is_legal(move))  // While loop to check if the combined 
                                     // column,row space is legal.
    {
        display_message("Illegal move.\n");
        move = get_user_move( );
    }
    make_move(move); // The two values should go into another function make_move
}
```

Thanks a lot for any help guys.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This

```
return column, row;
```

uses the [comma operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator), evaluating `column`, throwing away the result, and returning the value of `row`. So your function does not return two values.

If you want to return two values, you can write a struct holding two values, or use an [`std::pair<std::string, std::string>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair)

```
#include <utility> // for std::pair, std::make_pair

std::pair<string, string> othello::get_user_move( ) const
{
  ...
  return std::make_pair(column, row);
}
```

then

```
std::pair<std::string, std::string> col_row = get_user_move();
std::cout << col_row.first << "\n";  // prints column
std::cout << col_row.second << "\n"; // prints row
```

Answer (score 0):

use a string array  string[], store column into string[0] and row into string[1] and pass the string array around

Comment: `std::pair`, `std::vector` or any other container that obeys [value semantics](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?ValueSemantics) might be a better choice.